# Data from a Google Sheet "form" to a Google sheet spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that is in a “Form” format.  I need to program a button that once the sender completes the form, will send the data to another sheet in a spreadsheet format and erase the data from the “form” making it ready for another form entry.

Comment: isn't that how google forms work in general? they save responses to sheets and are ready for another form entry as long as you keep them enabled.

Comment: pls share you spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**enable goole sheets api service**, and adapt this script (names of source and destination sheets, and *cellsA1Notation* of data in source sheet).

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Validate Unit Registration (FORM)', 'copyDataRegistrationForm')
    .addItem(' Reset Unit Registration (FORM)', 'initRegistrationForm')
    .addToUi();
}
function copyDataRegistrationForm() {
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const srcSheet = "Unit Registration (FORM)";
  const dstSheet = "Master Data";
  const rngA1Notation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheet).getRange(1, 1, 1, 74).getValues().flat()
  const src = rngA1Notation.map(e => `'${srcSheet}'!${e}`);
  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: src })
  var data = []
  values.valueRanges.forEach(e => data.push(e.values ? e.values.flat().toString() : ""))
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheet).appendRow(data)
}
function initRegistrationForm() {
  const srcSheet = "Unit Registration (FORM)";
  const dstSheet = "Master Data";
  const rngA1Notation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheet).getRange(1, 1, 1, 74).getValues().flat()
  var rng = rngA1Notation.filter(r => SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(r).getFormula() == '')
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(srcSheet).getRangeList(rng).clearContent()
}
```

Comment: Mike how do I send you a link to my Google sheet and keep it private.

Comment: I have added the reset function (all ranges except those with formula)