# Googlesheet Script - Move to the next field after filling out and pressing enter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you help me out with my data entry form in Google Sheet. I need a script for when after filling out a field and pressing enter it moves to the next empty field. Also, is there a way to grey out all other unused cells in my data entry form or lock them so they wouldn't be touched like we can't put anything on them for example.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please help people in the community to be able to reproduce your setup by providing a sample sheet. Lastly, please include information such as things you have tried/researched before posting your question. Kindly review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

### Reference

[sheet.setActiveSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setactiveselectiona1notation)

### Script:

Try

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheetName'){                          // adapt
    var addresses = ["E7","H7","E10","H10","E13","H13","E16"]; // adapt
    var values = addresses.join().split(",");
    var item = values.indexOf(rng.getA1Notation());
    if (item < addresses.length - 1){ 
      sh.setActiveSelection(addresses[item + 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

This way you can determine the order in which the cells are selected.

If you have a script that copies cells into a master data sheet, you can take advantage of the range list. (by the way, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121814/data-from-a-google-sheet-form-to-a-google-sheet-spreadsheet/72122180#72122180) how to transfer the data).

### Edit:

If your sheet is protected, except for the cells that need to be filled in, you can use a script that will search for them and reorganize them.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheetName') {            // adapt
    var addresses = listOfUnprotectedRanges()
    var values = addresses.join().split(",");
    var item = values.indexOf(rng.getA1Notation());
    if (item < addresses.length - 1) {
      sh.setActiveSelection(addresses[item + 1]);
    }
  }
}
function listOfUnprotectedRanges() {
  var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => [r.getA1Notation(), r.getRow(), r.getColumn()])
  ranges = ranges.sort(function (a, b) { return a[2] - b[2]; }); // sort by columns 
  ranges = ranges.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; }); // sort by ranges first
  return ranges.map(r => r[0])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

> Note: This will only tackle the first question about ***moving active selection to the next empty field***. As for the locking of cells, kindly post a separate question for it as every question in Stackoverflow should focus only on one specific concern/issue.

You may try a combination of [Google Sheet onEdit(e) simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events), [`setActiveSelection`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setactiveselectionrange) method & a little bit of logic by getting the current row on your sheet. See this sample below:

### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //e.g. Sheet1 tab
  var col = e.range.getA1Notation().split('')[0];

  if (col == 'C' || col == 'F') { // runs only if selection is on col C or col F
    if (e.range.getRow() == 4) { //if user inputs on the search field
      var range = sheet.getRange(col + "" + (e.range.getRow() + 3));
      sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
    } else { //move to the next cells where each rows are in between one empty rows
      var range = sheet.getRange(col + "" + (e.range.getRow() + 2));
      return range.getRow() > (sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1) ? sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange('F7')) : sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
    }
  }
}
```

### Demonstration:

- Every time the `Enter` key is pressed after filling an empty field, the selector auto moves to the next empty field (a cell in white color).

[image]

> Note: This sample GIF was rendered in fast playback speed

### Limitations:

- Since this method calls the Spreadsheet App Service, there's a huge chance that it will run inconsistently/slowly if multiple triggers occur in a short period of time.
- After pressing `Enter`, the selector jumps to the next row for a few seconds then it'll auto move to the next empty field.
- Since we do not have a clear view of your actual sheet, this sample will only work if there is no other data on the sheet except for the one that is in your provided sample image. If this doesn't work as shown on the demonstration, kindly share your sample sheet so we can properly replicate your setup.

Comment: Hello! I tried pasting the code and it seems to be not working or maybe I miss something. Here's how my entry form looks like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chT7311UWsleuohBemAMpTBufxSoCBgpGlv8ZdhNb-A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnJacobSilaya Thanks for sharing your sample sheet. I tried the script on it and it seems to be working as seen [on my testing](https://imgur.com/a/t49ISso). Perhaps make sure it is saved on the bound script file of your spreadsheet Or reload your Spreadsheet file after saving the script & test it again.