# automatically move to the next cell on the page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet I designed in Google Sheets to input data at work and then a formula that determines if the part needs to be replaced and provides the part number required. I need either a macro or appScript that will start with a certain cell on the same sheet, highlight it, allow me to type a value in it, then either by pressing the ENTER or TAB key to move to the next cell on the page (Not necessarily the next door cell, but a cell in another column and/or row), -AND- based on a data validation check box determine which cells are selected. How do I write either a macro or appScript to do what I need? Which would be easier?

Comment: I think macro might be easier in this case since your use case is interactive. There's an optional to configure the macro in a relative cell sense, which would allow you to select the starting cell. Not sure what you mean by "next cell" (how's that defined in your case)?

Comment: There's not really a difference... Recording a macro in google sheets just creates an app script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reference

[sheet.setActiveSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setactiveselectiona1notation)

### Script:

Try

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheetName'){                          // adapt
    var addresses = ["E7","H7","E10","H10","E13","H13","E16"]; // adapt
    var values = addresses.join().split(",");
    var item = values.indexOf(rng.getA1Notation());
    if (item < addresses.length - 1){ 
      sh.setActiveSelection(addresses[item + 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

This way you can determine the order in which the cells are selected.

If you have a script that copies cells into a master data sheet, you can take advantage of the range list. (by the way, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121814/data-from-a-google-sheet-form-to-a-google-sheet-spreadsheet/72122180#72122180) how to transfer the data).

### In case of protected sheet:

If your sheet is protected, except for the cells that need to be filled in, you can use a script that will search for them and reorganize them.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheetName') {            // adapt
    var addresses = listOfUnprotectedRanges()
    var values = addresses.join().split(",");
    var item = values.indexOf(rng.getA1Notation());
    if (item < addresses.length - 1) {
      sh.setActiveSelection(addresses[item + 1]);
    }
  }
}
function listOfUnprotectedRanges() {
  var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => [r.getA1Notation(), r.getRow(), r.getColumn()])
  ranges = ranges.sort(function (a, b) { return a[2] - b[2]; }); // sort by columns 
  ranges = ranges.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; }); // sort by ranges first
  return ranges.map(r => r[0])
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have my sheet protected except for certain cells that get edited. I am very new to appScripts and know very little (but willing to learn). I'm running the second script you recommended for a protected sheet. I getting an error message of, TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ dataEntry.gs:8

Comment: You do not need to run the script yourself in the script editor. This script will be automatically executed when you enter the values in the unprotected cells.

Comment: It's not working and I don't know why. My first unprotected field is B1, the next unprotected field is E1, then B2:E2, next G2 next I2, next J2, next J2, next B3, next E4, next E5... If I could get just these to work I think I can program the rest of the cells to be used. I want to type information in each cell, press ENTER to move to the next cell, type the information and press ENTER to go to the next cell... I would like each cell highlighted to a certain color when it is ready for the information to be typed in then back to the original color after ENTER is pressed.

Comment: Do you try the first script or the second one with protected sheet? Can you share your spreadsheet or at least a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I copied and pasted the OnEdit function above into my appScript, changed the "mysheetname" to the sheet name. I'm getting an error on the line "var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();" saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ dataEntry.gs:8" How to fix this?

Comment: Do not run the script through the script editor. This is an onEdit script that runs automatically when you enter data into the sheet itself.

Comment: I placed the script in Extensions>Apps Scripts. If this is not the right place for the onEdit, then where do I put the script? I guess I need baby steps here.

Comment: yes, put the script in the editor in place of what it is proposed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnrun.png Save by clicking on the small icone (as a disk). That's all. Do not execute the script here. Go back to your sheet. Then you can begin to work, the cursor will go automatically to next cell when you have typed something.

Comment: The issue I'm having with the OnEdit function is when I enter a value in the first cell and press <ENTER> the script goes all the way to the end of the script to the last cell. I want to type information in the first cell, press <ENTER> and for the script to take me to the next cell for data entry. This is my test sheet, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Odn59hq8Kb32D1myCNzFvCCSuFGkoamdY1J5EaJvLME/edit#gid=0 I want to start at B1, type the information & <ENTER> go to B3 type <ENTER> go to E3 type <ENTER> go to D6 type.  How do I 'pause' the script for data entry in each selected cell?

Comment: This is the case with `var addresses = ["B1","B3","E3","D6"]` see your spreadsheet i which I put the script.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm reworking my shared spreadsheet (sample) so I can enter data on one tab (data) and have a button to press that will transfer the information to the SAMPLE page, to the cells indicated. I have a formula, 'submitData', but I can't get line 42 right. I've looked in multiple sites to try to fix this myself. I'm running out of options. How would I move this information from 'data' to 'sample'? This is a test spreadsheet. In the real spreadsheet I am working on,

Comment: I will have2 tabs each with between 200 and 400 individual cells to fill in and transfer. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this instead of typing each cell in the .getRange function?

Comment: Plz, don't mix different topics in one. Accept / upvote this answer if it responds to your expected behavior to move to the next cell. For your new need, you will have to use Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate. Post this new topic and I will be pleased to give you a solution.

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion, my bad.